# Screen video recording with sound in Android

Tags: android, android-mediaprojection

Currently I am developing an app which records video of mobile screens (screen recording) as per user interactions. Now I want to record video with audio or sound. How can I achieve this feature?

for video recording I am using following code:

```
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(videofilePath);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(3000000);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(24);
    mMediaRecorder.prepare();
    mMediaRecorder.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Insert This code

```
mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
```

Comment: I added same but It gives me exception:
java.lang.IllegalStateException
                      at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)

Comment: Add permission.RECORD_AUDIO

Comment: Doing same, just I am starting recording after click on button